# How create folder wise views in Sencha Architect?

Tags: extjs, extjs-mvc, sencha-architect

I am developing an Application in Sencha architect. My application is having different groups in it. In each group there are multiple modules and in modules there are no of views available. I want to have tree like folder structure for views. How to achieve this through Sencha architect.?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can put a prefix on each component name, example:

accounts.MainWindow

Will be generated as

/app/views/accounts/MainWindow.js

Answer (score -1):

You can have only MVC pattern.. You cannot have your own Tree structure in Sencha Architect!